# JQuery Form Validation not working on development browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

Good day. I am quite new to JavaScript and JQuery and I’m trying to add a form of validation to some form fields using JQuery.

I wrote a conditional statement that if the FULL NAME field is empty or less than 6, the HTML border-danger class will be added and there will be a message requesting the user to enter his/her full name.  Else (if he has entered his full name or the content of the field is greater than 6), the border danger class should be removed and the status variable should be changed to true.

I tried it out on my browsers and it wasn't working.

The trick about it is that when I tried to ask the question here on StackOverflow, on the HTML/JS/CSS code snippet page, it worked. The border-danger class was added to the FULL NAME field when I clicked on the REGISTER button without typing anything in the field.

Please why is it not working on my side? (Chrome and Opera). Is there something i need to enable?

I have attached the code of the registration form (register.php) and that of the JavaScript(main.js). I have also attached a screenshot of the registration form from Chrome.

I’m sure I must have mixed something up.

Please I need help. I’ll really appreciate the help.

Thanks in anticipation

[image: Screenshot of register.php from chrome]

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registration_form").on("submit",function(){
        var status = false; 
        var name = $("#full_name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var pass1 = $("#password1");
        var pass2 = $("#password2");
        var type = $("#usertype"); 
                                     
        if (name.val() == "" || fullName.length < 6 ) { 
            name.addClass("border-danger");
            $("#u_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please enter full name(More than 6 characters).</span>");
            status = false;
        }else{
            name.removeClass("border-danger");
            $("#u_error").html("");
            status = true;
        }

    })
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Inventory Management System</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <!--Include Navbar -->
      <?php include_once("./templates/header.php");?>

    <div class="container" ">

    <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 30rem; ">
            <div class="card-header">Register</div>
              <div class="card-body">

                <form id="registration_form" onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
             <!-- Full Name -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" id="full_name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
                    <small id="u_error" class="form-text text-muted">
                    </small>
                  </div>
              
                  <!-- Email -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="e_error" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                  </div>

                  <!--Password 1-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control"  id="password1" placeholder="Password">
                    <small id="p1_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Password 2  -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Re-enter Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control"  id="password2" placeholder="Password">
                    <small id="p2_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                  </div>

           <!-- User type -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usertype">Usertype</label>
                    <select name="usertype" class="form-control" id="usertype">
                      <option value="">Choose User Type</option>
                      <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                      <option value="Other">User</option>
                    </select>
                    <small id="t_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" name="user_register" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>&nbsp;Register</button>
                  <span><a href="index.php">Login</a></span>
                </form>
              </div>

              <!-- Forgot Password? -->

            <!--              
              <div class="card-footer text-muted" >
              <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div> -->
      </div>

    </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but, I think your current code above is wrong.
"if (name.val() == "" || fullName.length < 6 ) { ".
I didn't see any variable that named fullName here

Comment: Have you checked the browsers console for js errors? Also, why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: Thanks. I have done all that was recommended but it's still not working on WAMP. It works perfectly on JSFiddle and StackOverflow. Any further ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problem with your `if` condition and code.

1. You are not checking the length of anything at all
2. To check the length of input if its less then 6 you can do `name.val().length`
3. Also, you do not have to do like `name.val() == ""` this - just set`!name.val()` to false which means that there is no value in that input at all.
4. I could not find a `fullName` I am sure you want to use `name`

You can read more about `jQuery` - `.val()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

I have made some changes in your `if` and now is working fine below. You can do some `if` `else` for other input as well the same to validate all the inputs before sending data to your PHP file.

You file directory must be this *exact* as below: Copy the HTML below and put in `index.html` and JS in to `main.js` - I have tested this my wamp64 localserver and all is working fine.

**Location of main JS file:** file:///C:/wamp64/www/inventory_blessed/public_html/js/main.js

**Location of index.html:** file:///C:/wamp64/www/inventory_blessed/public_html/index.html

Fiddle **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/xob1d439/2/

Run snippet below to see it in action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registration_form").on("submit", function() {
    var status = false;
    var name = $("#full_name");
    var email = $("#email");
    var pass1 = $("#password1");
    var pass2 = $("#password2");
    var type = $("#usertype");

    if (!name.val() || name.val().length < 6) {
      name.addClass("border-danger");
      $("#u_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please enter full name(More than 6 characters).</span>");
      status = false;
    } else {
      name.removeClass("border-danger");
      $("#u_error").html("");
      status = true;
    }
    console.log(status)
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Inventory Management System</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Include Navbar -->
  <?php include_once("./templates/header.php");?>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 30rem; ">
      <div class="card-header">Register</div>
      <div class="card-body">

        <form id="registration_form" onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
          <!-- Full Name -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" id="full_name" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
            <small id="u_error" class="form-text text-muted">
                    </small>
          </div>

          <!-- Email -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="e_error" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>

          <!--Password 1-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password">
            <small id="p1_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
          </div>

          <!-- Password 2  -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password2">Re-enter Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Password">
            <small id="p2_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
          </div>

          <!-- User type -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usertype">Usertype</label>
            <select name="usertype" class="form-control" id="usertype">
              <option value="">Choose User Type</option>
              <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
              <option value="Other">User</option>
            </select>
            <small id="t_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="user_register" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>&nbsp;Register</button>
          <span><a href="index.php">Login</a></span>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Forgot Password? -->

      <!--              
              <div class="card-footer text-muted" >
              <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div> -->
    </div>

  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of the assistance. The `fullName` and `full_name` discrepancy in the code happened when i was thought that the JQuery was not working because of the case, i changed it from full_name to `fullName` . Same thing happened to the path `../js/main.js`. I was trying to debug it and i changed it from `./js/main.js` to `../js/main.js`. I forgot to revert it too. This is the file path `C:\wamp64real\wamp64\www\inventory_blessed\public_html\js\main.js` I've changed my IF statement and the file path yet its not working. I wonder why it's working in JSFiddle and StackOverflow but not on WAMP.

Comment: @Timothy I have just your code and main.js in my local wamp64 server - AND its all working fine. I have edited my answer and added some info for you. Please follow the exact same structure and all should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the help. These file paths can be a little tricky. I changed it from `<script src="./js/main.js"></script>` to `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` and it worked. Thanks once again @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Timothy Glad that i was able to help. Please accept my answer as a solution and do not forget to up-vote as well so it helps other too. Thanks :)

Comment: @Timothy I have upvoted your question already. You can click on the Tick ✅ mark in my answer and to upvote my answer press the grey tick up next to my asnwer or follow this guide on how to mark an answer as solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks i have done that. Sorry I haven't done that earlier. I'm having problems with my wamp loading pages and I guess it's making all my JavaScript not to load properly. I have to create another question for that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you are not loading right path of the `main.js` file at line `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>`. I guess your folder stucture is something like this:
your_folder:

-----| js

----------| main.js

-----| view_folder

----------| index.html

With your current code, maybe the problem you are facing right now is you are using the virtual local likes `www.localhost.com/view_folder/index.html` I think
So the solutions is, you should try to change the path

from `".../js/main.js"` to `"/js/main.js"`, in order to tell the browser to call to "www.localhost.com/js/main.js",

For not facing the bug related to path, I recommend not to use `../..` or `./` on file in `script` tag or `link` tag, use `/file.js` or `file.js` instead.

`../js/main` is relative path, so it's will only work well when the file you are opening is also relative path (like double click on html file or directly open the file). All the file path that is included in html file should not be used like that, because the domain maybe different sometime.

To know that your `js file` path is right or wrong, just try to open the dom in DevTools, and right click, open the link at `src="../js/main.js"`.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the path issues and it's still not working. This is my file path `C:\wamp64real\wamp64\www\inventory_blessed\public_html\js\main.js`. Everything works perfectly on JSFiddle and StackOverflow but it doesn't work on my WAMP. Any ideas why?

Comment: can you provide the path after you updated the code ? And did you check the path whether it's right ?

Comment: Thanks @ThienHuynh , @AlwaysHelping helped me to fix it. I changed it from `<script src="./js/main.js"></script>` to `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` and it works. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do it like this

```
 $('#full_name').on('change', function(){
      if ($('#full_name').length <6){
        $('#full_name').addClass('border-danger');
      }
 });
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what you've changed, what problem it solves and why.